# How to send string input from Visual Basic to Arduino over serial port?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, arduino

I'm trying to get a string input received in Visual Basic to print out on an LCD monitor on my Arduino. I know I will need to the console.write function for VB, and the lcd.writeline for Arduino, but how do I send the string from Visual Baisc to the Arduino over a serial port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in vb2010 expres edition drag a com port on your project, configure a proper bautrate
here a handy page http://tiktakx.wordpress.com/2010/11/21/serial-port-interfacing-with-vb-net-2010/

For arduino side use this reference
check commands on the right side of the page here: http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Serial

You might as well join their forum you get excellent help there too.